# Function to show/hide div(s) not showing all of the second option

Tags: javascript, show-hide

Just stuck with a problem on a web page I'm making. Also, still new to JS.

I have hidden two divs with display:none; and written some JS to change one or other div based on a  value.

I've managed to get that to work, but when I select the not-partici value, the full div is not showing. It only shows on the text inputs when there should be two. I am struggling to find where I went wrong.

Here is the html:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/299fe5d3f3.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/form.css" />

<html>
    <head>
        <title>Bahloo Country</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/main.css" />
    </head>
    <body class="is-preload">

        <!-- Navbar -->
        <div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
            <a href="#home" class="active">Home</a>
            <a href="#news">About</a>
            <a href="#contact">Services</a>
            <a href="#about">Contact</a>
            <a href="#about">Apply</a>
            <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">
              <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
            </a>
          </div>

        <!-- Header -->
            <section id="header" class="dark">
                <header>
                    <div class="hedo"><h1>Participant Application Form</h1>
                    <p>Become a Participant of Bahloo Country's services!</p><br>
                    <p>Bahloo would like to acknowledge the traditional custodians of the land in which we work, live and learn, the land of the Bundjalung Nation. We pay our respects to elders of the past, present and future emerging</p><br>
                    <p>May we all work together, within the best of our ability, to preserve the knowledge of our lore, land and culture to preserve for the future generations, and continue to build the strength of our community.</p>
                    </div></header>
            </section>
        </div>

    
<section id="first" class="main">
    <form action="" method="get">
    <div class="rendered-form">
        <div id="detailsSec">

        <label for="iddecade" class="formbuilder-select-label">Are you the participant or applying on behalf of someone?<span class="formbuilder-required">*</span></label>
        <select class="decade" name="iddecade" id="idParticipant" onchange = "formStarter()" required="required" aria-required="true">
            <option disabled selected value> -- select an option -- </option>
            <option value="participant" id="idpartici-0">I am the participant</option>
            <option value="not-participant" id="idpartici-1">I am applying on behalf of someone</option>
        </select>

        <!-- If person completing form = participant-->

        <div id="partici" style="display:none;">
            <label for="undefined" class="formbuilder-text-label">Name of Person Completing Form<span class="required">*</span></label>
            <input type="text" class="fullname" access="false" id="control-2763896" title="Enter your full name" required="required" aria-required="true" name="undefined">
        </div>

        <!-- If Person completing form = not-participant -->
        <div id="not-partici" style="display:none;">
            <label for="undefined" class="formbuilder-text-label">Name of Person Completing Form<span class="required">*</span></label>
            <input type="text" class="fullname" access="false" id="control-2763896" title="Enter your full name" required="required" aria-required="true" name="undefined">

            <label for="undefined" class="formbuilder-text-label">Participant's full name<span class="required">*</span></label>
            <input type="text" class="fullname" access="false" id="control-2763896" title="Enter your full name" required="required" aria-required="true" name="undefined">
        </div>
        <p>placeholder</p>
    </div>
    </div>
    </form>
    </section>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
@import url("fontawesome-all.min.css");
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,100italic,300,300italic,400,400italic");
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Knewave&display=swap');


html, body, div, span, applet, object,
iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote,
pre, a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite,
code, del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var, b,
u, i, center, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset,
form, label, legend, table, caption, tbody,
tfoot, thead, tr, th, td, article, aside,
canvas, details, embed, figure, figcaption,
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, output, ruby,
section, summary, time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;}

article, aside, details, figcaption, figure,
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;}


.topnav {
    background-color: #333;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
  }
  
  
  .topnav a {
    color: #f2f2f2;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 17px;
    transition: 1s;
  }
  
  
  .topnav a:hover {
    background-color: rgb(223, 122, 8);
    color: black;
    padding: 16px 30px;
    transition: 1s;
  }
  
  
  .topnav .icon {
    display: none;
  }



body {
    line-height: 1;
}

h1 {
    font-family: 'Knewave';
}

ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}

blockquote, q {
    quotes: none;
}

    blockquote:before, blockquote:after, q:before, q:after {
        content: '';
        content: none;
    }

table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}

body {
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: none;
}

mark {
    background-color: transparent;
    color: inherit;
}

input::-moz-focus-inner {
    border: 0;
    padding: 0;
}


/* Basic */

    @-ms-viewport {
        width: device-width;
    }

    html {
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    *, *:before, *:after {
        box-sizing: inherit;
    }

    body {
        background: #F8F8F8;
        font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
        font-weight: 300;
        font-size: 17pt;
        line-height: 1.75em;
        color: #888;
    }

    .dark {
        color: #aaa;
        color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.65);
    }

    input, textarea, select {
        font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
        font-weight: 300;
        font-size: 17pt;
        line-height: 1.75em;
        color: #888;
    }

    h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
        color: #666;
        margin: 0 0 1em 0;
        font-weight: 100;
        line-height: 1.5em;
    }

    h1 a, h2 a, h3 a, h4 a, h5 a, h6 a {
        color: inherit;
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    .dark h1, .dark h2, .dark h3, .dark h4, .dark h5, .dark h6 {
        color: #fff;
    }

    strong, b {
        font-weight: 400;
        color: inherit;
    }

    .dark strong, .dark b {
        color: #fff;
        color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.85);
    }

    em, i {
        font-style: italic;
    }

    a {
        -moz-transition: border-bottom-color 0.25s ease-in-out;
        -webkit-transition: border-bottom-color 0.25s ease-in-out;
        -ms-transition: border-bottom-color 0.25s ease-in-out;
        transition: border-bottom-color 0.25s ease-in-out;
        color: inherit;
        border-bottom: dotted 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
    }

        a:hover {
            border-bottom-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
        }

    .dark a {
        color: #fff;
        border-bottom-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
    }

        .dark a:hover {
            border-bottom-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
        }

    sub {
        
        top: 0.5em;
        font-size: 0.8em;
    }

    sup {
        
        top: -0.5em;
        font-size: 0.8em;
    }

    hr {
        border: 0;
        border-top: solid 1px #e6e6e6;
        margin: 2em 0 2em 0;
    }

    .dark hr {
        border-top-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
    }

    blockquote {
        border-left: solid 0.25em #e6e6e6;
        padding: 1em 0 1em 2em;
        font-style: italic;
    }

    .dark blockquote {
        border-left-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
    }

    p, ul, ol, dl, table {
        margin-bottom: 1em;
    }

    p {
        text-align: justify;
    }

    header {
        margin-bottom: 1em;
    }

        header h1, header h2, header h3, header h4, header h5, header h6 {
            margin: 0;
        }

        header p {
            display: block;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0.25em 0 0.5em 0;
        }

    footer {
        padding-top: 1.5em;
    }
/* Container */

    .container {
        margin: 0 auto;
        max-width: 100%;
        width: 1360px;
    }

        .container.medium {
            width: 1020px;
        }

        @media screen and (max-width: 1680px) {

            .container {
                width: 1200px;
            }

                .container.medium {
                    width: 900px;
                }

        }

        @media screen and (max-width: 1280px) {

            .container {
                width: 960px;
            }

                .container.medium {
                    width: 720px;
                }

        }

        @media screen and (max-width: 1000px) {

            .container {
                width: 100% !important;
            }

        }

/* Row */



        @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
            .topnav a:not(:first-child) {display: none;}
            .topnav a.icon {
              float: right;
              display: block;
            }
          }

          @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
            .topnav.responsive {position: relative;}
            .topnav.responsive a.icon {
              position: absolute;
              right: 0;
              top: 0;
            }
            .topnav.responsive a {
              float: none;
              display: block;
              text-align: left;
            }
          }



/* Image */

    .image {
        
        display: inline-block;
        border: 0;
    }

        .image:after {
            content: '';
            
            left: 0;
            top: 0;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            background: url("images/overlay.png");
        }

        .image img {
            display: block;
            width: 100%;
            border-radius: 0.5em;
        }

        .image.featured {
            display: block;
            width: 100%;
            margin: 0 0 2em 0;
        }

        .image.fit {
            display: block;
            width: 100%;
        }

        .image.left {
            float: left;
            margin: 0 2em 2em 0;
        }

        .image.centered {
            display: block;
            margin: 0 0 2em 0;
        }

            .image.centered img {
                margin: 0 auto;
                width: auto;
            }


/* Header */

.hedo {
    border: solid;
    border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
    background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    max-width: 1200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

    #header {
        
        margin: 0;
        background-image: url("images/overlay.png"), url("../../images/header.jpg");
        background-size: auto, cover;
        background-position: top left, center center;
        background-repeat: repeat, no-repeat;
        padding: 14em 0 14em 0;
        text-align: center;
        color: #fff;
    }

        #header header h1 {
            font-size: 2.25em;
            line-height: 1.25em;
            margin-bottom: 0;
        }

        #header header p {
            margin-top: 1.25em;
            font-weight: 100;
            padding: 0;
            font-size: 1.25em;
            line-height: 1.5em;
            text-align: center;
        }

        #header footer {
            padding-top: 1.5em;
        }

/* Main Sections */

    .main {
        margin: 0;
    }

        .main > header {
            background: #fff;
            text-align: center;
            padding: 5em 0 5em 0;
            margin: 0;
        }

            .main > header h2 {
                font-size: 2.25em;
                font-weight: 100;
                margin-bottom: 0;
            }

            .main > header p {
                margin: 2em 0 0 0;
                padding: 0;
                text-align: center;
            }

    

            #first {
                width: 50%;
                margin: auto;

            }

            div > #skillsetssec {
                border: solid;
                border-radius: 5px;
                padding: 15px;
                margin: 30px 0px;
            }
        #skillsetssec > label:not(.formbuilder-checkbox-group-label) {
            padding: 25px 0px;
        }

        div > #detailsSec {
            border: solid;
            border-radius: 5px;
            padding: 15px;
            margin: 30px 0px;
        }

        div > #expSec {
            border: solid;
            border-radius: 5px;
            padding: 15px;
            margin: 30px 0px;
        }

        div > #workPrefSec {
            border: solid;
            border-radius: 5px;
            padding: 15px;
            margin: 30px 0px;
        }

        #daysAvbl {
            border-top: solid;
            border-bottom: solid;
            margin-top: 10px 0px;
        }

        div > #vehDetailsSec {
            border: solid;
            border-radius: 5px;
            padding: 15px;
            margin: 30px 0px;
        }

        div > #formsSec {
            border: solid;
            border-radius: 5px;
            padding: 15px;
            margin: 30px 0px;
        }

        input[type="file"] {
            margin-bottom: 45px;
            margin-top: 20px;
            padding-bottom: 30px;
            padding-top: 20px;
            border-bottom: solid;
            border-right: solid;
            border-top: solid;
            border-radius: 5px;
            width: 100%;
        }

        .btn {
            text-align: center;
        }

        button[type="submit"] {
            margin-bottom: 50px;
            padding: 40px 100px;
            font-size: 30px;
        }
/* Footer */

    #footer {
        
        margin: 0;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 4em 0 8em 0;
        box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 0 #e6e6e6;
    }

        #footer .copyright {
            margin-top: 3em;
            font-size: 0.8em;
            color: #aaa;
        }

            #footer .copyright a {
                color: inherit;
            }

        #footer ul.icons a {
            box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px #d6d6d6;
        }

/* Wide */

    @media screen and (max-width: 1680px) {

        /* Basic */

            body, input, textarea, select {
                font-size: 15pt;
                line-height: 1.75em;
            }

    }

/* Normal */

    @media screen and (max-width: 1280px) {

        /* Basic */

            body, input, textarea, select {
                font-size: 13pt;
                line-height: 1.65em;
            }

        /* Feature Icon */

            .feature-icon {
                margin-bottom: 2em;
            }

        /* Header */

            #header {
                padding: 12em 0 12em 0;
            }

        /* Main Sections */

            .main > header {
                padding: 4em 0 4em 0;
            }

            .main > .content {
                padding: 4em 0 4em 0;
            }

    }

/* Narrow */

    @media screen and (max-width: 1000px) {

        /* Basic */

            header, footer, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, header > p {
                text-align: center;
            }

        /* Sections/Article */

            section, article {
                margin: 0 0 2.5em 0 !important;
            }

            .row > section, .row > article {
                margin: 0 0 2.5em 0 !important;
            }

        /* Table */

            .table-wrapper {
                width: 100%;
                overflow-x: scroll;
                padding-left: 1px;
                -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
            }

        /* Header */

            #header {
                margin: 0 !important;
                padding: 8em 2em 8em 2em;
            }

                #header header p {
                    margin-top: 1em;
                }

                #header footer {
                    padding-top: 1.25em;
                }

        /* Main Sections */

            .main {
                margin: 0 !important;
            }

                .main > header {
                    padding: 3.5em 2em 3.5em 2em;
                }

                    .main > header h2 {
                        font-size: 1.85em;
                    }

                    .main > header br {
                        display: none;
                    }

                    .main > header p {
                        margin: 1.5em 0 0 0;
                    }

                .main > .content {
                    padding: 3.5em 20px 3.5em 20px;
                }

                    .main > .content > .container > :last-child {
                        margin-bottom: 0 !important;
                    }

        /* Footer */

            #footer {
                margin: 0 !important;
                padding: 3em 0 3em 0;
            }

                #footer .copyright {
                    margin-top: 2em;
                }

    }


    .coreSupImg {
        border-radius: 50%;
        width: 50%;
    }

    #testies {
        border-radius: 50%;
        max-width: 200px;
        max-height: 200px;
    }
/* Mobile */

    @media screen and (max-width: 736px) {

        /* Basic */

            body, input, textarea, select {
                font-size: 11pt;
            }

        /* Sections/Article */

            section, article {
                margin: 0 0 1.5em 0 !important;
            }

            .row > section, .row > article {
                margin: 0 0 1.5em 0 !important;
            }

        /* Button */

            .button {
                padding-left: 0;
                padding-right: 0;
                width: 100%;
                max-width: 24em;
            }

        /* Icons */

            ul.icons li {
                padding-left: 0.35em;
            }

        /* Menu */

            ul.menu li {
                border: 0;
                padding: 0;
                display: block;
                margin: 1em 0 1em 0;
            }

        /* Header */

            #header {
                padding: 6em 20px 6em 20px;
            }

                #header > header {
                    padding: 0 1em 0 1em;
                }

        /* Main Sections */

            .main > header {
                padding: 3em 20px 3em 20px;
            }

                .main > header h2 {
                    font-size: 1.5em;
                }

            .main > .content {
                padding: 3em 20px 3em 20px;
            }

                .main > .content h3 {
                    font-size: 1.25em;
                }

    }
```

Here is the JS:

```
(function($) {

    var $window = $(window),
        $body = $('body');

    // Breakpoints.
        breakpoints({
            wide:    [ '1281px',  '1680px' ],
            normal:  [ '1001px',  '1280px' ],
            narrow:  [ '737px',   '1000px' ],
            mobile:  [ null,      '736px'  ]
        });

    // Scrolly.
        $('.scrolly').scrolly();

})(jQuery);

function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
    if (x.className === "topnav") {
      x.className += " responsive";
    } else {
      x.className = "topnav";
    }
  }

function formStarter() {
    var a = document.getElementById("idParticipant");
    var partici = document.getElementById("partici")
    var notPartici = document.getElementById("not-partici")

    if (a.value == 'participant'){
        partici.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        notPartici.style.display = "block";
    }
}
```

Note: I'm editing over a template so it's a complete mess with most likely plenty of unused code...

Comment: You have multiple elements with the same `id` attribute, The id is unique for the page. If you use `getElementById()` only one element will be selected.

Comment: I can't see where I doubled up on id tags? Is there a quick way I can search for this on vs code?

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to find the answer, as Gert B mentioned in the comments. I did not think I had id attributed the same, but im guessing it turns out that hyphens can omit other  the remaining words, causing the getElementById selector to screw up and select take either one as partici.

After i changed the id="not-partici" to id="notPartici" I had no issues.